# Advanced custom fields on two post type - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to add fields with php in two pages (in ***advanced custom fields plugin*** , ***wordpress***)

Here is my try :

```
acf_add_local_field_group(array (
    'key' => 'songs_options',
    'title'      => 'songs options',
    'fields' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'field_1',
            'label' => 'test title',
            'name' => 'test_field',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array (
        array (
            array (
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => 'IN', 
                'value' => array( 'songs', 'videos'),  // i need a code like this line
            ),
        )
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `==` operator with the locations, and add every location as a different array under 'location':

```php
register_field_group(array (
    'key'    => 'songs_options',
    'title'  => 'songs options',
    'fields' => array (
        array (
            'key'   => 'field_1',
            'label' => 'test title',
            'name'  => 'test_field',
            'type'  => 'text',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array (
        array (
            array (
                'param'    => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==', 
                'value'    => 'songs',
            ),
        ),
        array (
            array (
                'param'    => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==', 
                'value'    => 'videos',
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: thanks , I have changed "IN" to "==" , the boxes are added  in two post types

Comment: but I cant (publish / update  ) post ( in post edit wp-admin ) ! whene I use this function

Comment: sorry, i've forgot to change the "IN" in the copy-paste! :P now it's edited

Comment: does wordpress print any error when you click publish/update?

Comment: after I click on it, console says : TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a
 - jquery.js   -http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3

Comment: I'm testing it, and it works for me with the register_field_group function but not with the acf_add_local_field_group! does this function work for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106925/discussion-between-danial-dezfooli-and-vicent-ibanez).